# Android : my button image is enlarged in the app?

Tags: android, image, button

I use a button with an image as its background, this image has a size of 30x29, but it's resized and enlarged x2 (I think). Here is the XML code of my button :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bouton_back"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:maxWidth="30dp" />
```

And in Java :

```
backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
```

What is wrong with that ? I do the same with other buttons and there is no problem... thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you supplying `bouton_back` in your resources using multiple densities? Using `dp` units to size your button isn't sufficient; you must also [provide multiple sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) of your images:

- ldpi:  120dpi
- mdpi:  160dpi
- hdpi:  240dpi
- xhdpi: 320dpi

The conversion formula is as follows:

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

Where `px` is the final image size in pixels, `dp` is the desired size in density-independent units, and `dpi` is the target density.

Simplifying this formula, using the size in pixels of your `mdpi` images as the baseline:

```
ldpi = mdpi * 0.75
hdpi = mdpi * 1.5
xhdpi = mdpi * 2.0
```

Going back to your sample code, if you want a button that is 30dp by 30dp, you should be providing images for each density:

- ldpi: 23px x 23px
- mdpi: 30px x 30px
- hdpi: 45px x 45px
- xhdpi: 60px x 60px

Answer (score 1):

I think that may be folder issue. Where have you put the image file? (possibly there would not be a problem if You have it in `drawable-hdpi`)

EDIT

ps - there is also a dp unit thing, which is pixel-independent.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the *background* property, android will stretch your image depending on the device resoulution in dpi (**ldpi**, **mdpi**, **hdpi** and **xhdpi** screens), if you put your image in drawable-mdpi folder, your image will stretch according to this coefficient

[image]